# Color ggplot based on interaction of two catergorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is sample code.
I want to color points based on values of flag and choice (there are 4 possible combination since both variables are binary).

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- runif(10)
y <- runif(10)
z <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
flag <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
choice <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)

tbl <- tibble(x, y, z, flag, choice)

scatterplot <- ggplot(tbl,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y),
                      color = factor(interaction(choice, flag)),
                      size = 1) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue3", "cyan1", "red3", "oran")) +
  facet_grid(z ~ .) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right") + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggtitle("Scatter plot")

scatterplot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1. Set your color attribute inside of aes(). That way, the feature will be used for coloring.
2. "oran" is not a color, try with [http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Etzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf) (I set it to "orange").

### Code

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- runif(10)
y <- runif(10)
z <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
flag <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
choice <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)

tbl <- tibble(x, y, z, flag, choice)

scatterplot <- ggplot(tbl,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          color = factor(interaction(choice, flag))),
                      size = 1) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue3", "cyan1", "red3", "orange")) +
  facet_grid(z ~ .) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "right") + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggtitle("Scatter plot")

scatterplot
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks @carrasco, but there is an issue of overlapping in this, which is not visible because we used very small data. I don't know how can I add a plot in comment so I will modify the question.

Comment: @SiD happy to help :)

Comment: Can you please help with the modified question.

Comment: @SID I'd post that modification as a different quesiton. I am not sure about the solution for it, though. Reordering the factor may solve it (maybe apply reorder_within to the interaction from tidytext since you're using tidyverse). But if a plot does not show what you intend, you may want to consider using another representation, I'd go for a heatmap with geom_tile, but that may not be what you want.

Comment: I have asked the question again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343179/overlaying-points-in-specific-manner-in-ggplot-scatter-plots